# Get XSD from RESTful Web API

Tags: c#, rest, xsd

I have created simple RESTful Web API with automatic documentation from Swagger on [Azure](https://webapidemo20220427161453.azurewebsites.net/) by using  C# :

```
namespace WebAPIDemo.Controllers
{
    
    public class ValuesController : ApiController
    {
        // GET api/values
        public IEnumerable<string> Get()
        {
            return new string[] { "value1", "value2" };
        }

        // GET api/values/5
        public string Get(int id)
        {
            return "value";
        }

        // POST api/values
        public void Post([FromBody] string value)
        {
        }

        // PUT api/values/5
        public void Put(int id, [FromBody] string value)
        {
        }

        // DELETE api/values/5
        public void Delete(int id)
        {
        }
    }
}
```

It is possible to call function from [Swagger](https://webapidemo20220427161453.azurewebsites.net/swagger/ui/index#/Values).

How to get XSD schema for this service?

Answer (score 0):

Swagger does not generate metadata as XSD - metadata is published only as JSON, following the [OpenAPI specification](https://swagger.io/docs/specification/about/). If you use your browser to inspect the Swagger UI page for your example website, it makes an XHR call to `https://webapidemo20220427161453.azurewebsites.net/swagger/docs/v1`, which returns the following JSON:

```
{"swagger":"2.0","info":{"version":"v1","title":"WebAPIDemo"},"host":"webapidemo20220427161453.azurewebsites.net","schemes":["https"],"paths":{"/api/Values":{"get":{"tags":["Values"],"operationId":"Values_Get","consumes":[],"produces":["application/json","text/json","application/xml","text/xml"],"responses":{"200":{"description":"OK","schema":{"type":"array","items":{"type":"string"}}}}},"post":{"tags":["Values"],"operationId":"Values_Post","consumes":["application/json","text/json","application/xml","text/xml","application/x-www-form-urlencoded"],"produces":[],"parameters":[{"name":"value","in":"body","required":true,"schema":{"type":"string"}}],"responses":{"204":{"description":"No Content"}}}},"/api/Values/{id}":{"get":{"tags":["Values"],"operationId":"Values_Get","consumes":[],"produces":["application/json","text/json","application/xml","text/xml"],"parameters":[{"name":"id","in":"path","required":true,"type":"integer","format":"int32"}],"responses":{"200":{"description":"OK","schema":{"type":"string"}}}},"put":{"tags":["Values"],"operationId":"Values_Put","consumes":["application/json","text/json","application/xml","text/xml","application/x-www-form-urlencoded"],"produces":[],"parameters":[{"name":"id","in":"path","required":true,"type":"integer","format":"int32"},{"name":"value","in":"body","required":true,"schema":{"type":"string"}}],"responses":{"204":{"description":"No Content"}}},"delete":{"tags":["Values"],"operationId":"Values_Delete","consumes":[],"produces":[],"parameters":[{"name":"id","in":"path","required":true,"type":"integer","format":"int32"}],"responses":{"204":{"description":"No Content"}}}}},"definitions":{}}
```

But, if your API itself returns XML (and not JSON), then you can still describe the XML result using the [OpenAPI facilities given here](https://swagger.io/docs/specification/data-models/representing-xml/). It does not support XSD (so the metadata and type information is still returned as JSON), but this still does provide some basic type information for your API consumers to use.